# PostgreSQL: Как удалить из массива все объекты по значению?

Tags: postgresql

Есть массив объектов в формате jsonb:

```
{
    "images": [
        {"filename": "11"},
        {"filename": "22"},
        {"filename": "33"},
        {"filename": "11"}
    ]
}
```

Можно ли удалить из массива все объекты, которые имеют `"filename": "11"`, не зная по какому ключу удалять?

Подсмотрел, как другие решают подобную проблему, однако выражение ниже работает, только, если `"filename": "11"` в массиве встречается один раз. Если значений несколько, то выдается ошибка `"ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки"`.

```
    UPDATE tbl
       SET data = data #- coalesce(('{images,' || (
                SELECT i
                  FROM generate_series(0, jsonb_array_length(data->'images') - 1) AS i
                 WHERE (data->'images'->i->'filename' = '"11"')
             ) || '}')::text[], '{}');
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с изменяемым JSON в Постгресе не принесёт вам ничего, кроме *боли.* Нормализуйте свои данные и используйте нормальную реляционную модель, пока не поздно.

А то, что вы хотите, можно сделать так:

```sql
UPDATE t SET
  data = jsonb_set(data, ARRAY['images'], result.arr) FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(filtered.elem) FROM (
      SELECT arr.elem FROM (
        SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'images') AS elem FROM t
      ) AS arr(elem) WHERE elem <> '{"filename":"1"}'
    ) AS filtered(elem)
  ) AS result(arr);
```